# android phonegap geolocation emulator

Tags: cordova

I try to get get coordinates using geolocation on android emulator on phonegap platform. but it seems to not work. The code should be right, I add permission in manifest, use the highacuracy tag,  how can I address this problem? Thanks !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError,{ enableHighAccuracy: true });
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                            'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                            'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                            'Timestamp: '          + new Date(position.timestamp)          + '<br />';
    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Set geolocation in the emulator as follows, go to DDMS in eclipse and choose emulator set lantitude,longitude enter image description here

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the location in the simulator?

e.g:

```
$ telnet localhost 5554
$ geo fix -4.2 55.85
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of the emulator are you using?  If you are using 2.3.x, be aware that geolocation doesn't seem to work: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13046

You have to go down to 2.2.